# Apache POI Workbook throws java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to instantiate a `Workbook` with this code:

```
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(excelWorkbookFilePath));
```

I do it this way because the workbook can either be `.xlsx` or `.xls`. However, it ends up throwing this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:65)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:601)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:174)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:249)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:293)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:252)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:231)
    at com.iconectiv.handle.ExcelHandle.<init>(ExcelHandle.java:43)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:56)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:62)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setLoadEntityBytesLimit(I)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLTypeLoader.<clinit>(POIXMLTypeLoader.java:50)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.<init>(ThemesTable.java:85)
    ... 15 more
```

I did some research and found out that `InvocationTargetException` is not the real exception, so I tried to catch it with this `catch` statement:

```
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    e.getCause().printStackTrace();
}
```

However, I get an error in Eclipse saying that I can't catch that as it is never thrown from anything. Why am I getting this error? Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Note: I am using Apache POI 3.14.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The actual error getting thrown is
 `NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setLoadEntityBytesLimit(I)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;`

Possibility you don't have xmlbean jar in your class path or you might have multiple version of jars

Comment: I have `xmlbeans-2.5.0.jar` in my class path. Do I need to upgrade?

Comment: Trying upgrading and also make sure you don't have multiple versions of same jar

Comment: I am trying to upgrade, but I only see version 1.0 in Apache Attic... Where can I get version 2.6 that is listed on the XMLBeans website?

Comment: I don't see a download link there. My project doesn't use Maven. I clicked on 2.6.0.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works now. What did you click to get to that repo1 link? I didn't see anything on the website.

Comment: I am using POI 4.0 and xmlbeans 2.6.0 still getting the same error .. any idea guys?

Answer (score 1):

You can instantiate the workbook separately for .xls and .xlsx extension based on the file name:

```
Workbook wb = null;
    if (fileName.endsWith(".xlsx")) {
        wb = new XSSFWorkbook(in);
    }else{
        fs = new POIFSFileSystem(in);
        wb = (Workbook) new HSSFWorkbook(fs);   
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, however this was giving me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the pom with same version. Earlier I have different version 3.9.0 for poi-ooxml and 4.0 for poi

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
```

It worked for me